# Exporting Drupal 6 blog as CSV

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am using Drupal 6 for a client and i want to export Blog entry as a CSV along with the title and Body content and images.

I have installed Views data export Module and went to

views ---> add  and gave views name like:
blog
blog_entry
export_test

and from view type I tried:
node
node_revisions

but it says:
**It seems the page you are looking for does not exist. Please make sure you typed the address correctly, or try again later.**

How do I export it?

Comment: check this out https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate

Answer (score 0):

I think you must read the README.txt of module that you are using. As you said you are using it with Drupal 6, check the following instruction into the modules README.txt http://cgit.drupalcode.org/views_data_export/tree/README.txt?h=6.x-3.x.

```
Using the "Views Data Export" module
------------------------------------

1. Add a new "Data export" display to your view.
2. Change its "Style" to the desired export type. e.g. "CSV file".
3. Configure the options (such as name, quote, etc.). You can go back and do
   this at any time by clicking the gear icon next to the style plugin you just
   selected.
4. Give it a path in the Feed settings such as "path/to/view/csv".
5. Optionally, you can choose to attach this to another of your displays by
   updating the "Attach to:" option in feed settings.
```

Hope this will help!